# $http.get response is undefined

Tags: python, angularjs, frontend, backend

I am working on an front end at the moment,and using python for back end. Front end is html and i am using angularJs for the communications.

My issue is that I cannot get the response from python backend, though it is called properly, a list is generated and i write result as following (in my python code)

```
self.write({"success":True, "data":list})
```

But, angular code does not recieve any responses. Just success (http 200OK) status code is returned. How can I make the backend successfully send the list as response?

Btw, angular code is

```
$scope.init = function () {
     //Take the list of applications from database
     var req = {
         method: 'GET',
         url: 'http://localhost:8888/app',
         headers: {
           'Content-Type': "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
         }
     }
     $http(req).success(function(data) {
         $scope.results = response.data
         // response is undefined??
     } )
    .error (.......);
```

Comment: Maybe try console.log(data)? How it looks right now response would be undefined because the you are getting back just data from the function. Basically the difference between .success(function(response)) vs what you have which is .success(function(data))

Comment: Console.log gives me -> Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":null,"status":-1,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"http://localhost:8888/app","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":"","xhrStatus":"error"}

Comment: Replace your function(data) with function(response) because right now response is undefined as it's literally not passed in anywhere or initialized anywhere.

Comment: Still undefined and console gives the same output

Comment: Maybe take a look at this https://www.codelord.net/2015/05/25/dont-use-%24https-success/. Apparently the better way to do this would be the .then() notation so perhaps look into that.

Answer (score 3):

try changing your success callback to :

```
$http(req).success(function(response) {
         $scope.results = response.data;
})
```

you are capturing the param as variable named `data` in your success callback method and trying to access `response` variable inside your method, which is actually not defined.

Comment: Thank you, but when I do this response is also undefined, nothing changed.

Comment: then, capture network traffic on your browser, and verify if your REST call is actually returning any response object in this case

Comment: Yes I also did that, response comes as wanted,{"success":true, "apps" : { ....(app list)....} } is returned. But angularjs seems to not know about this response...

Comment: what does `console.log(response)` gives you ?

Comment: It gives Object { data: null, status: -1, headers: zd(), config: {…}, statusText: "", xhrStatus: "error" } and the response now returns HTTP405 OPTIONS response..